# Iterate through List of case objects replace NaNs and write it back in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, case-class, type-mismatch

I have a `List` of case objects of which some values are `NaN`s and I have to replace them with `0.0`. So far I tried this code:

```
var systemInformation: List[SystemInformation] = (x.getIndividualSystemInformation)

systemInformation.foreach[SystemInformation] {
  _ match {
    case SystemInformation(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, x) if x.isNaN()
      => SystemInformation(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, 0.0)
    case SystemInformation(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, x) if !x.isNaN()
      => SystemInformation(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, x)
  }
}
```

But that does not write the changes back to `systemInformation`. So I added another List but got a type mismatch:

```
var systemInformation: List[SystemInformation] = (x.getIndividualSystemInformation)

var systemInformationWithoutNans: ListBuffer[SystemInformation] = new ListBuffer[SystemInformation]
systemInformation.foreach[SystemInformation] {
  _ match {
    case SystemInformation(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, x) if x.isNaN()
      => systemInformationWithoutNans += SystemInformation(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, 0.0)
    case SystemInformation(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, x) if !x.isNaN()
      => SystemInformation(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, x)
  }
}
```

The error occurs on the line with the `+=` and is the following:

```
type mismatch;
found : scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[com.x.interfaces.SystemInformation]
required: com.x.interfaces.SystemInformation
```

Why does this not work? What would be a better way to replace the `NaN`s with `0.0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `map` instead of `foreach`.

Your first solution is basically the right way to go, but `foreach` only iterates over all elements, whereas `map` allows to map the elements from type `A` to `B` returning a new collection of type `B`.

Comment: Do you mean like this: `systemInformation.map( _ match { CODE FROM ABOVE })`? That does not replace anything. Am I using it the wrong way?

Comment: yes, but you have to store the result: `val modifiedList = oldList.map(...)`

Answer (score 4):

Use map as bluenote10 sugested, but additionally, what about:

```
val transformedSystemInformation = systemInformation map (_ match {
    case s:SystemInformation if s.x.isNan() => s.copy(x = 0.0)
    case _ => _
})
```

Comment: +1 I was just about to edit my question with a similar suggestion but due to distraction, you were faster :)

Comment: `case _ => _` gave me an "unbound placeholder parameter" error. So I replaced it with case `a:SystemInformation => a` which works.

Comment: `xs map (_ match {...})` can be written as `xs map {...}`

Comment: @sschaef I tried that but the `if` condition showed an error.

Answer (score 1):

Since your first question is not answered above, I thought I would add that this doesn't work, because the method `+=`

```
def +=(x: A): ListBuffer.this.type
```

returns a `ListBuffer[SystemInformation]` in this case, but you have parameterized `foreach` by the type `SystemInformation`

```
foreach[SystemInformation]
```

which is why the compiler is expecting the type `SystemInformation` rather than `ListBuffer[SystemInformation]` and returns the error

```
type mismatch;
found : scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[com.x.interfaces.SystemInformation]
required: com.x.interfaces.SystemInformation
```

If, on the other hand, you remove the type parameterization from foreach, your example will compile:

```
...
systemInformation.foreach { ... }
...
```

For a better approach, used [Ian McMahon's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15071544/307255) suggested approach.